# RHEL7 /boot deleted from fstab

Tags: linux, boot

Running RHEL7 Virtual Machine in my home lab.
/boot is separated from "/".

```
root@localhost ~# grep part anaconda-ks.cfg -A4
clearpart --none --initlabel
# Disk partitioning information
part pv.251 --fstype="lvmpv" --ondisk=sda --size=12808
part /boot --fstype="xfs" --ondisk=sda --size=512
volgroup rhel --pesize=4096 pv.251
logvol swap  --fstype="swap" --size=512 --name=swap --vgname=rhel
logvol /home  --fstype="xfs" --size=1024 --name=home --vgname=rhel
logvol /  --fstype="xfs" --size=11264 --name=root --vgname=rhel
```

I deleted "/boot" entry from /etc/fstab to see what will happen(I expected an error about missing grub2 or initramfs). But what happens is nothing! RHEL7 boots up and login prompt presented to me and I am able to login to the system. I can not figure out how grub2, then initramfs, and kernel have been loaded without /boot?

Comment: added an important note to the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can not figure out how grub2, then initramfs, and kernel have been loaded without /boot?

Because all those things will have already happened before /etc/fstab is read.

1. the firmware loads GRUB
2. GRUB loads the kernel & initramfs;
3. the kernel starts init;
4. init reads /etc/fstab.

Therefore neither the firmware nor GRUB can depend on /etc/fstab – they use their own mechanisms:

- BIOS firmwares always run the bootcode from the disk's 0th sector (where the MBR is). In your case, that 0th sector would have the GRUB stage1.
- UEFI firmwares keep boot configuration in NVRAM – the RHEL installer configures it to look for `grubx64.efi` in an "EFI system partition", which is detected by UUID.
- Once GRUB is started, it already knows *its own* partition, finds `grub.cfg` in it, and searches for the Linux kernel based on UUID defined there. (Of course, `grub.cfg` is often *generated* based on fstab contents during installation.)

(GRUB has its own drivers for ext4 and even LVM. Some bootloaders, e.g. systemd-boot, use UEFI to access files in the "EFI system partition". LILO used to remember the kernel's sector position on disk, I think.)

---

The other reason is that /etc/fstab is an OS-specific configuration, therefore having GRUB directly depend on it would prevent it from correctly booting operating systems which don't have such a fstab.

(The same is even more important for the first step (firmware loading GRUB). Just think about it – if /etc/fstab was required for that, how would the firmware boot Windows?)

---

Note, however, that `/boot` needs to be in fstab – or mounted some other way – for *kernel updates* to work correctly. If you forget to mount /boot, the next upgrade will install new modules but not the kernel itself. Since you cannot mix different kernel and module versions, the system won't boot correctly.